# Why does this not work? ("Cannot find symbol")

Tags: java, class, object, symbols

I just don't know what i did wrong.

1.

```
public class HDD {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int iops; 
        Platter platter;

        System.out.println(platter.plattergroesse);
        }
}
```

2.

```
public class Platter {

Sektoren sektoren;

int plattergroesse() {
    return sektoren.groesse * sektoren.anzahl;
}
}
```

If I try to compile the HDD.java, following happens:

HDD.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(platter.plattergroesse);
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable plattergroesse
  location: variable platter of type Platter
1 error

It would be great, if someone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plattergroesse` is a method, but you access it as an instance variable.

For a method call, you need `platter.plattergroesse()`.

Of course, you'll have to initialize the `platter` variable to avoid `NullPointerException`.

To summarize :

```
    Platter platter = new Platter ();
    System.out.println(platter.plattergroesse());
```

But you'll also have to initialize the `sektoren` member in the `Platter` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `plattergroesse` as a function ("method", in Java), since that's what it is. Like so: `System.out.println(platter.plattergroesse());`